# How does react.js detect a keypress and how to simulate it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to programatically send a message on whatsapp web.
First I inject some jquery on the page to make it easier to select components.
I then set the content of the input box with:

```
$(".input").html("This is a test message");
```

When switch back from the console to the page, I try to press enter to submit the field and the message does not send, but when I type something, it enables sending.

So I figured there must be some event being triggered where it detects that there is content being typed on the field, so I tried triggering: "change", "keyup","keydown", and many other events, but still it does not enable submission.

Since I'm not familiar with react, I'm now curious of how it detects the input.

When I press the letter "E" on my keyboard, there is a browser limited number of events that javascript (and therefore, react) can identify, right? I would say, "keydown", "keyup" and "keypress", but still, react does not pick up when I trigger these programatically, only when I actually type on my keyboard.

My question: How does react.js detect a keypress and how can I trigger these events programatically?

Answer (score 0):

you can use onChange event to capture your text.

```
 class X extends React.Component{   
        changeEvent()
        {

        this.setState({
                [e.target.name] : e.target.value
            }); 

        }

           render(){
          return (

          <div>
    )
    }
    }

            <input type="text" name="firstname" onChange={this.changeEvent.bind(this)}
        <div>
        )
```